# Create an email link with area shape

Tags: html, xhtml, dreamweaver

Hi everybody I am working with Dreamwaver and there is an image which I have used with `area shape` to create an email link ,but don't know how can I write the code to detect the email:

```
  <area shape="rect" coords="322,165,395,243" />
```

Comment: with shape area I can use URL links is there any way to put email address instead of url ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would this not work?

```
<area shape="rect" coords="322,165,395,243" href="mailto:us@example.org" />
```